# MVEL Date Formatter

Tags: html, mvel

I want to display date as dd/MM/yyyy where I am getting ![getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3XgG.png)

here is my Code

```
<tr>               
    <td  height="25"><strong>Account Statement Date</strong></td>
    <td  height="25"><strong>Closing Date</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td  height="25">@{data.startDate}</td>
    <td  height="25">@{data.endDate}</td>
    </tr>
```

data contains dateobject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer for this we can directly include java code in MVEL by Importing required packages

```
@{
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
  String startDate = formatter.format(data.startDate);
  String endDate = formatter.format(data.endDate);
}
```